Lower bounds of Sinc function by rational functions
Theorem 1 of this article is

For any $x ∈ [0, π]$, one has
$$
\operatorname{sinc}(x) \geqslant \frac{16 \pi^4}{\left(3 \pi^2+x^2\right)^2}-1
$$

Its proof of Theorem 1 uses the inequality (4): $\operatorname{sinc}(x) \geqslant \frac{53}{53+9 x^2}, \quad 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{3}$. But I can't find a proof of this inequality $(4)$, so I can't completely understand its proof of Theorem 1.
Can you provide a proof of Theorem 1 without using this inequality $(4)$, or a proof of the inequality $(4)$?

This article and this article proved a similar inequality:  $\frac{-7 x^2+60}{3 x^2+60}<\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ by repeated differentiation.
I tried to apply the same method to prove $(4)$ but failed, because the method in these articles relies on that the derivative of $\sin(x)-x\left(\frac{-7x^{2}+60}{3x^{2}+60}\right)$ is nonnegative on $(0,\pi)$, but the derivative of $\sin (x)-x\left(\frac{53}{53+9 x^2}\right)$ is not always nonnegative on $(0,\frac13)$ (it has a root near $0.308$).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737372/monotonic-c-infty-bounds-on-the-sinc-function/4944115#4944115 could be of interest for you

The reference [1] in that article does not give the source (only give (4) as well). However, this inequality is weak. It is enough to use the well-known $\sin x \ge x - x^3/6$ to prove it. We have $1 - x^2/6 - \frac{53}{53+9 x^2} = \frac{x^2(1-3x)(1+3x)}{6(9x^2 + 53)}\ge 0$ for all $0 \le x \le 1/3$.

Here is a proof of Theorem 1 without using this inequality $(4)$:
Using Euler's infinite product formula
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\prod_{n\ge1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)$$
Pulling out the first 3 factors:
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\prod_{n\ge2}\left(1+\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{(n+1)\pi}\right)$$
Since $\left(1+\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{(n+1)\pi}\right)>1$ on $(0,\pi)$, we get a polynomial lower bound for sinc function:
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)>p(x):=\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)$$
Since $p(x)-\left(\frac{16\pi^{4}}{\left(3\pi^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}-1\right)=\frac{(\pi-x)^2(x+\pi)\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2 x^2+\frac{19}{4} \pi ^2 \left(x-\frac{10 \pi }{19}\right)^2+\frac{51 \pi ^4}{19}\right)}{2 \pi^3\left(x^2+3 \pi^2\right)^2}>0$,
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)>p(x)>\frac{16\pi^{4}}{\left(3\pi^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}-1$$
on $(0,\pi)$.

I noticed that it is your question. :/ Have you checked the site rules?

@BobDobbs Yes, I came up with 2 proofs of Theorem 1 without using the inequality $(4)$, but the original article's proof used $(4)$ so I hope to see a proof of $(4)$.

Here is another proof of Theorem 1 without using this inequality (4):
Let $f(x)=\frac{\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2\right)^2}{16 \pi ^4\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}+1\right)}$
$f'(x)=-\frac{\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2\right) \left(-4 x^3-\left(5 x^2+3 \pi ^2\right) \sin (x)+\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2\right) x \cos (x)\right)}{16 \pi ^4 (x+\sin (x))^2}$
Let $g(x)=-4 x^3-\left(5 x^2+3 \pi ^2\right) \sin (x)+\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2\right) x \cos (x)$
$g'(x)=-x \left(\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2+10\right) \sin (x)+2 x (\cos (x)+6)\right)<0$ on $(0,\pi)$.
So $g(x)<g(0)=0$ on $(0,\pi)$.
So $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi)$.
So $f(x)<f(\pi)=1$ on $(0,\pi)$.
So $\frac{\left(x^2+3 \pi ^2\right)^2}{16 \pi ^4}<\frac{\sin (x)}{x}+1$ on $(0,\pi)$.
